# Flurry Event Occurrences Are 0

Tags: android, flurry, flurry-analytics

We have Flurry Analytics setup for our app and its been working fine. However in November something seems to have affected our plugin because our Android events dropped to about 10% of what they used to be.

I have setup a test scenario where I am logging some test events. The odd thing is the event is FIRING (because its the first time that event ever could exist) and I know that its making to Flurry because it shows up in the event list.

[image]

However the occurrence is 0 for all of these. I have waited over 8 hours before confirming that its still 0.

Do you know why my events are firing and reaching Flurry but the event occurrences won't go up?

**Update 1**

My `FlurryAnalytics` Jar Version is 6.2.0

Here is my sample code. I am using a [plugin](https://github.com/jfpsf/flurry-phonegap-plugin/blob/master/src/android/Flurry.java) (we use Cordova) but its pretty straight forward code:

```
    FlurryAgent.init(this, "FLURRY_KEY");
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "FLURRY_KEY");
    FlurryAgent.logEvent("*Android Test3");
```

**Update 2**

> W/FlurryAgent: Flurry session paused for context:co.app
>
> W/FlurryAgent: Flurry session ended
>
> W/FlurryAgent: Analytics report sent.
>
> W/FlurryAgent: Flurry session started for context:co.app
>
> W/FlurryAgent: Flurry session resumed for context:co.app
>
> W/FlurryAgent: Event count started: *Android Test3
>
> W/FlurryAgent: Analytics report sent.

Comment: What version of Flurry? Can you post the code that you are using?

Comment: I've updated my question with that info.

Comment: Have they still not shown up? Can you turn on logging: `FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true)`, `FlurryAgent.setLogEvents(true)` and `FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.INFO)` to make sure everything is working?

Comment: I had done that before and I get lots of messages saying everythings a go. I'll post a log.

Comment: It looks like everything is working. It maybe a delay on Flurry's backend.

Comment: Just checked now and the events are firing (from last night at least). Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: No problem. I think you should move your updates into an answer(post your own answer). This is a good step by step walkthrough.